# Color set distance

Tags: algorithm, colors

I parsed images with [Color thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) and get their domain color and percentages. ex:

```
const colorSet = [{
  r: 15, g:251, b:150, percentage: 50 // cover percentage in image
}, {
  r: 150, g:121, b:45, percentage: 31
}, {
  r: 43, g:160, b:180, percentage: 19 
}]
```

I already know how to get the distance between two colors, but how about two "Color Sets"? Is there any algorithm to do this?

[EDIT]
I think vector is a way... but not sure about the detail.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a matter of calculating the average of each set and then taking the distance of these averages?

Comment: @Nyerguds What's the "average"? You means like `(r1 * p1) + (r2 * p2) + ... / 100`? I don't think the output make sense...

Comment: uh, average of [r1, g1, b1], [r2, g2, b2] and [r3, g3, b3] would be [(r1+r2+r3)/3, (g1+g2+g3)/3, (b1+b2+b3)/3], no?

Comment: @Nyerguds no, you must have percentages in.

Comment: What does "percentage" mean in this context? Alpha? You can just include that the same way if you want to include it in the average calculation.

Comment: Edit for more describe.